# Multiplicación con numero anterior en vector (Java )

Tags: java

tengo una duda con este pequeño programa que estoy desarrollando en java el cual tengo un vector de tamaño 10, el cual me piden ingresar un número en la primera posición del vectory las demás posiciones se irán llenando con el elemento de la posición anterior * 2, no se que me esta fallando o si algo estoy haciendo mal

Muchas Gracias por sus colaboraciones

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    int i=0;
    int[] lista = new int [10];
    int numero;

    System.out.println("Ingrese un numero por favor: ");
    numero = entrada.nextInt();

    for (i =1; i <lista.length; i++) {
      if(i==1){
            lista[i] = numero*2;
            System.out.println("numero[" + i + "]= "+lista[i]);
         }

       lista[i]=lista[i]*2;
      System.out.println("numero[" + (i+1) + "]= "+lista[i]);
     }


}
```

}

Comment: Imagina que vas a asignarle un valor a lista en su posición 2, que valor tendrá?.. y si ese valor lo multiplicas por 2 que valor tendrá `0 = 0 × 2` También estás asignando el primer valor 2 veces, aunque lo imprimes de tal manera que no parece esto que te digo. Si no contesta nadie en un par de horas te digo algo, y si lo consigues solucionar pues mejor :)

Comment: Es un problema de lógica deberías darle una vuelta al código. Dos apuntes: 1.- La primera posición de un array es la 0  y 2.- Revisa los indices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te doy esta solución... y ahora te explico los porquéss..

```
public class MultiplicaPorDos {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] lista = new int[10];
        int numero;

        System.out.println("Ingrese un numero por favor: ");
        numero = entrada.nextInt(); //se asigna el primer valor ingresado al primer inidice de la lista

        for (int i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                lista[i] = numero;
                System.out.println("numero[" + i + "]= "+lista[i]);
            }
            else {
                lista[i] = lista[i-1] *2;
                System.out.println("numero[" + i + "]= "+lista[i]);
            }

        } //fin for
    }
}
```

**Resultado:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Declaramos e inicializamos en 0 el valor de `i`. La primera posición de un vector o array es la `0`

```
for (int i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
```

La primera vez que recorra el bucle for entrará en el if, ya que su valor 'i' será 0, y será la única vez que entre dentro de este condicional, ya que a cada vuelta de bucle incrementará su valor en 1.

```
if (i == 0) {
       lista[i] = numero;
       System.out.println("numero[" + i + "]= "+lista[i]);
}
```

Las demás vueltas del bucle entrará dentro del else, ya que no se cumplirá la condición del if, salvo en la primera vuelta o recorrido.
También a lista[i], le daremos el valor de la vuelta anterior multiplicado por 2.

```
else {
   lista[i] = lista[i-1] *2;
   System.out.println("numero[" + i + "]= "+lista[i]);
}
```

También especificar, que si no le ponemos el `else`, en la primera vuelta le asignará un valor a la posición lista[0] dos veces, y eso no es correcto.

Comment: Buenísima explicación, positivo que va.

Comment: Gracias @Pablo Simon DiEstefano. La verdad es que se agradece. :)

Comment: Nada, igual que se puntúa negativo a una mala respuesta hay que dar positivos a las buenas, es la manera de que esto sirva de algo. sigue así porque nos ayudas mucho =)

Comment: @DiegoLoL Muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de leer y responder, me quedo mucho mas claro con la explicación y ya lo corregi y me quedo funcionando, Mil gracias

Comment: De nada @Zukhoi, para eso estamos o se intenta ;). Si crees que cualquiera de las respuestas que se te ha dado te ha ayudado deberías darla por contestada para ayudar al mantenimiento del sitio. Saludos https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

para empezar estás asignando la multiplicación al número actual del arreglo y no al anterior, la razón de que los dos primeros te salgan bien es que estás tomando el número directo cuando el for es 1 y porque el segundo estás tomando el valor recién asignado.

Tu código podría quedar así

```
int i=0;
int[] lista = new int [10];

System.out.println("Ingrese un numero por favor: ");
lista[0] = entrada.nextInt(); //se asigna el primer valor ingresado al primer inidice de la lista

for (i =1; i <lista.length; i++) {
  if(i==1){
        lista[i] = lista[i-1] *2;// se multiplica el valor anterior por dos y se asigna
        System.out.println("numero[" + i + "]= "+lista[i]);
  }
  //esto se tiene que eliminar dado que está de más 
  //lista[i]=lista[i]*2;
  //System.out.println("numero[" + (i+1) + "]= "+lista[i]);
```

}

No tengo a la mano algo para probar el código, pero en dado caso solo serían errores de sintaxis, la idea ya está

Comment: Muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de leer y responder, lo probe y me funciono perfecto. mil gracias